# spring webflux - don't create session for specific paths

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-session

My spring webflux service exposes a health-check endpoint, which is called every few seconds. `spring-security` is configured, and currently each health-check call creates a new session, which fills the `SessionStore` quickly.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
  return http
    .authorizeExchange()
      .pathMatchers("/actuator/*").permitAll()  // disable security for health-check
      .anyExchange().authenticated()
    ...
    .and().build();
}
```

logs:

```
2020-07-23 21:58:03.805 DEBUG 4722 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [b185e815-1] HTTP GET "/actuator/health"
2020-07-23 21:58:03.845 DEBUG 4722 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.s.s.DefaultWebSessionManager       : Created new WebSession.
```

Is it possible to configure `spring-session` or `spring-security` to not create sessions for specific paths?

Comment: Did you try to specify `.securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())`?

Comment: This will stop creating security context for any request. My goal is to create the context for certain requests only.

Comment: You can configure more than one ServerHttpSecurity per path

Comment: how do you mean? This is invalid: `.pathMatchers("/actuator/*"). securityContextRepository(...)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783145/reactive-spring-security-5-1-3-release-multiple-authorizations

Comment: Sessions are created even with `.securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())`